# HTML div as a text input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using a div as text input and the problem is that the cursor flashes at the beginning of the String on a second attempt to edit the field. During my initial attempt, it does allow me to write left to right.

The other problem is two-way binding. The div is being concatenated multiple times.

I have the below code:

```
  <div class="css-462">
                <div class="-hr-454">
                  <div class="-r9-455">  {{question.no}}.</div>
                  <div class="-hv-467 transparent">
                    <div class="-hv-483">
                      <div aria-label="Question title 2 Input your question title here" [classList]="generateClassName()"  role="textbox" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" style="user-select: text;">{{printText()}}</div>
                      <input aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                      <div></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

As you can see the printText method returns text from a map.

I am trying to imitate the dual binding using javascript. I place the value on a map.
The problem, is the set method is supposed to replace the existing value. In my case, it is being concatanted.

```
 setInterval(() => {
        if(!this.IsQuestionnaireTitle) {
          if(getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionToQNo" + this.dataId)!=null && getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionToQNo" + this.dataId).length != 0) {
            console.log(getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionToQNo" + this.dataId));
            //this.question.texts.delete("en");
            this.question.texts.set("en", getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionToQNo" + this.dataId));
          }
        }
        if(this.IsQuestionnaireTitle) {
          if(getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionTitleField")!=null && getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionTitleField").length != 0) {
            this.questionnaireTitle = getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionTitleField");
          }
          if(getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionnaireDesc")!=null && getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionnaireDesc").length != 0) {
            this.questionnaireDescription = getTextLabelOnTOTenWidget(".questionnaireDesc");
          }
        }
      }, 100)
```

Comment: It's because of the template. If I use an input it would not be as nice as the template

Answer (score 1):

For two way binding with contentEditable, use this custom directive.
I will just try to solve two way binding for contentEditable here not much.

I am using `innerText` in the directive for contentEditable setting and getting value.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { distinctUntilChanged, fromEvent, map, Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[twoWay]'
})
export class TwoWayBindingDirective {

  @Input('twoWay') value: any;

  @Output('twoWayChange') emitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
  destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.innerText = this.value;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let onInput$ = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'input');
    onInput$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map((event: any) => event.target.innerText)
      ).subscribe(
        value => {
          this.emitter.emit(value);
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

To use this in template

```html
<div class="css-462">
    <div class="-hr-454">
        <div class="-hv-467 transparent">
            <div class="-hv-483">
                <div [(twoWay)]="obj.name" aria-label="Question title 2 Input your question title here" role="textbox"
                    tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" style="user-select: text;">
                    ContentEditable Text
                </div>
                <!-- <input aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"> -->
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```